# Eliminating smaller values in an array

Tags: javascript

I have an array like so:

```
const dynamicNumber = 4
const array = [10, 15, 20, 25, dynamicNumber]
```

So what i would like to do, is eliminate all the terms that are smaller than that dynamic number.
So in this case, I would like to create a copy of the array and remove the values which are greater:

```
const newArray = [4]
```

Comment: try `.filter`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Check out [array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```js
const dynamicNumber = 4
const array = [10, 15, 1, 2, 20, 25, dynamicNumber]
const filteredArray = array.filter(number => number < dynamicNumber)

console.log(filteredArray)
```